# codeigniter session becomes value 'css'

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, session

I have a very strange thing going on.
The value of my session always becomes 'css' after a while.
Can you guys please have a look?

```
public function index($step = 13)
{
    if(!$this->session->userdata('laststep') && $step != 13)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('laststep', $step);
    }
    if($step > $this->session->userdata('laststep') && $step != 13) 
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('laststep', $step);
    }
    if($step < $this->session->userdata('laststep'))    
    {
        redirect(base_url().'main/index/'.$this->session->userdata('laststep'));
    }
}
```

every time, the link goes 1 step up.
It goes fine for 2 clicks or something and then I come in the 3rd if scenario and being redirected to /main/index/css

Where the hell comes that 'css' from. How can the value of my session change into that?

Comment: Please check value of last step before redirect to it ....

Comment: @WellWisher I did that, but it says 'css' as well

Comment: Then check where that CSS came from & remove ....

Comment: Look to the code, I don't have any idea where it comes from..